# Does netstat command show devices, printers on your wifi network?

Tags: macos, networking, netstat

What network utility on a MAC can help me see what devices, printers are available, listening etc on my wifi. Netstat does not seem to show me my printer or Android device. For example,

My macbook pro with ip address 10.1.140.255 but I can't see my Android phone with ip 10.1.140.77 or a printer on 10.1.140.95.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that some of your devices may be passively just sitting there with no active connections to your computer, you can't find them by examining your computer; you'll have to go actively looking for them. That typically means a network scanner.

Here's a list: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/network-scanning-tools/

I like Nmap (https://nmap.org) with the Zenmap GUI (https://nmap.org/zenmap)

Just make sure you do this in your own network. Scanning somebody else's network will trigger alarms and is more than likely illegal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with Wireshark but haven't used it in a minute. I will attempt further testing using this tool. Thanks.

Comment: Wireshark is a network "sniffer", or [packet analyser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Packet_Sniffer), and can tell you about the network traffic, whereas Nmap is a network scanner, or [port scanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner), and is used for finding network devices, and services on those devices. They are complementary tools, and both are quite useful once you have learnt to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `arp -a` instead. Netstat doesn't scan the network, it just provides information about your own device's connection to the network.

**Edit:** Try `ifconfig | grep broadcast | arp -a`

When you're on LAN, connecting to an IP involves resolving the IP into a mac address. ARP keeps a cache of all resolved IP addresses. Doing a broadcast ping indirectly triggers a resolution for all IPs on the network.

https://superuser.com/questions/124453/how-can-i-scan-the-local-network-for-connected-devices-mac-os

Comment: arp -a didn't show it either. Did not even show my macbook ip address.

Comment: Maybe first ping the broadcast address? ("ifconfig | grep broadcast")

Comment: ifconfig | grep broadcast did show me my macbook address but that's it. These commands are for devices connected via LAN not WiFi ...